# Xslt: how to parse and echo xml datas with conditions

Tags: xml, xslt

I would need to use xslt to do something like this:

```
foreach(product as product{
    if(itemType == "processor" && price < 100$) echo processor["brand"]
    if(itemType == "laptop" && color=="black") echo laptop["price"]

)
```

I try since 2 days to use xslt `<xsl:for-each>` statement and also `<xsl:if>` statement but I definitely do not know
how to use it correctly even after having seen some web tutorials. Can anyone helps me please ?

```
<myShop>
    <product itemType="processor">
        <brand>Intel</brand>
        <price secondHand="false">230$</price>
        <nbCore>4</nbCore>        
    </product>
        <product itemType="processor">
        <brand>Amd</brand>
        <price secondHand="true">90$</price>
        <nbCore>2</nbCore>        
    </product>
    <product itemType="laptop">
        <brand>Dell</brand>
        <price secondHand="false">600$</price>
        <color>black</color>
    </product>
    <product itemType="laptop">
        <brand>Apple</brand>
        <price secondHand="true">900$</price>
        <color>silver</color>
    </product>
</myShop>
```

Edit:
Please look at this Xml code

```
<agency>
    <product productType="appartement">
        <price transactionType="rent">1000€</prix>
        <location>Paris</location>
        <surface>80m²</surface>
        <bedroom>1</bedroom>
        <bathoom>2</bathoom> 
        <heating heatingType="gaz">yes</heating>
    </product>       
    </product>
    <product productType="house">
        <price productType="sell">280000€</prix>
        <location>London</location>
        <surface>190m²</surface>
        <bedroom>3</bedroom>
        <bathoom>2</bathoom> 
        <heating heatingType="electric">yes</heating>
    </product>
</agency>
```

And here is my Xslt stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>agence.xsl</title>
            </head>
            <body>                
                //help me echo house having price > 200000 and price < 300000 and having bedroom >= 3 order by location, surface desc                 
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Could you help me echo house having price > 200000 and price < 300000 and having bedroom >= 3 order by location, surface desc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two small templates should do:

> if(itemType == "processor" && price < 100$) echo processor["brand"]

Here we use **translate()** to remove the `$`

```
    <xsl:template match="product[@itemType='processor' and number(translate(price,'$','') ) &lt; 100 ]">
        <xsl:value-of select="brand"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

> if(itemType == "laptop" && color=="black") echo laptop["price"]

```
    <xsl:template match="product[@itemType='laptop' and color = 'black']">
        <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

And a third one as **"else"** (to ignore the not matching ones)

```
    <xsl:template match="product"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. Finaly your answer helped me a lot.